# Efficiency of analysing exported SQL data sheet in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for the long title.

I have been given a large flat file to be analysed in SQL server, which was generated by another SQL database which I do not have direct access to. Due to the way the query had been generated, there are over 5000 different rows, for only 900 unique objects.

My question is a straightforward one: I am not attempting to create a long term database. Would it more time-efficient to to split this back into separate tables to re run queries, or would it be easier to analyse it as is?

Comment: You mean like denormalized vs normalized? No need to normalize in this case, you will not be updating the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5,000 rows is not a large table.  The time and effort to reverse engineer a "normalised" database, and write and debug the ETL, will not be repaid in reduced runtime.  Index it well for your queries and remember to put a `DISTINCT` in where it's required.  You'll be fine.